# Handle Template Error using ErrorHandler in angular2

Tags: angular, error-handling

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040698/5043867) , i get to know that after using `Errorhandler` in our module angular will not throw any such error and our app works somthly,

i did the same process and works fine,

Problem :- After handling template parse error using `ErrorHandler`  will make all buttons/dropdown on that page and other pages not working properly, is there any kind of method in angular2 by using which neither angular will throw error nor webapp stuck (like buttons are not working in template) ?

Comment: I have found some work around and replied [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040698/how-to-handle-template-errors-and-other-errors-in-angular-2)